# Rails Blazer Gem. The map is not shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, token, mapbox

I have a rails project and i am using the Gem Blazer.

When I use a query that should create the map this is not shown. A bar graph is shown instead.

Can this be due to the mapbox token?

[image]

I have the mapbox token configured in the shared section of secrets.yml

[image]

Anyone knows whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the update to Rails 5.2, the file secrets.yml don´t work anymore.

I simply put the variable in the development.rb just like that:
ENV['MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'] = "token is here".

Problem Solved